# Show that a function maps a region into the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that the following function maps the indicated region into the unit circle.

$$f(z) = e^{i \Psi}\frac{z^{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}} - a}{z^{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}} - \bar{a}}$$

where $\Psi \in \mathbb{R}$, $Im(a) \gt 0$, and D is the wedge $ 0 \lt arg(z) \lt \alpha$.

I am having great difficulty with this problem, especially where to begin.  Do I parameterize z within the wedge somehow?

Comment: What exactly is $\Re$?

Comment: $\Re$ is $\mathbb{R}$, the set of all real numbers.  I changed it in the question as well.

Comment: Oh ok, got it. usually denoted $\mathbb R$, I see you edited it

Comment: Well $e^{i\Psi}$ has absolute value 1, so you can ignore that part and just work with the fraction.

Comment: What do I do with the fraction?  I see that it is a Linear Fractional Transformation of some sort.

Comment: You need to show $z^{\pi/\alpha}$ is closer to $a$ than it is to $\bar a$.  So since $a$ is in the upper half plane and $\bar a$ is in the lower half you need to show $z^{\pi/\alpha}$ is in the upper half plane.  Does that help?

Comment: Why would showing that $z^{\pi/\alpha}$ is in the upper half plane show that the region D is mapped into the unit circle?

Comment: I think that does it, think in polar coordinates about what raising to a power does to $z$.

Comment: Because it would show $z^{\pi/\alpha}$ is closer to $a$ than to $\bar a$.  Thus $\left|\frac{z^{\pi/\alpha}-a}{z^{\pi/\alpha}-\bar a}\right|=\frac{|z^{\pi/\alpha}-a|}{|z^{\pi/\alpha}-\bar a|}$ and the numerator is less than the denominator, so this ratio is less than one, so it lands inside the unit circle.

Comment: Since $(e^{i \theta})^{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}}$ = $e^{i \theta \frac{\pi}{\alpha}}$ is why the wedge maps into the unit circle.  That makes sense now.  I will work on proving that $z^{\pi/\alpha}$ is closer to $a$ that $\bar{a}$.

Comment: This definitely does it, because $\pi/\alpha$ is exactly the largest power of $z$ that leaves it still in the upper half plane.

Comment: Your last comment makes me think you may still be a bit confused.  The wedge maps to the upper half plane by $z\mapsto z^{\pi/\alpha}$.  That forces the fractional part to have absolute value less than one.  The other part $e^{i\Psi}$ is irrelevant because it has absolute value exactly one.

Comment: I tried to write it up and post a complete answer below, let me know if that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z$ is in the wedge, the angle $z$ makes with the real axis is at most $\alpha$, so the angle $z^{\pi/\alpha}$ makes with the real axis is at most $\pi$, so $z^{\pi/\alpha}$ is in the upper half plane.  Thus since $\text{im}(a)>0$, $z^{\pi/\alpha}$ is closer to $a$ than it is to $\overline a$.  Thus
$|z^{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}} - a|<|z^{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}}-\overline a|$.  Thus

$$\left|e^{i \Psi}\frac{z^{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}} - a}{z^{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}} - \bar{a}}\right|$$
$$=\left|e^{i \Psi}\right|\cdot\frac{|z^{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}} - a|}{|z^{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}} - \bar{a}|}$$
$$=1\cdot \frac{|z^{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}} - a|}{|z^{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}} - \bar{a}|}$$
$$<1$$

Comment: It makes sense.  I think the last comment I made above was poorly worded, as I did understand what you were saying.  I just finished working through from the comments that you gave above and it finally makes sense.  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.